# Python - Como organizar uma linha do excel a partir do python?

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-excel, pandas

Olá, esta é a minha primeira pergunta aqui, não sei se estou a perguntando corretamente, mas vamos lá.

A partir do funcionalidade "concat" do pacote pandas, eu estou juntando vários arquivos excel, o código que faz o mesmo eu encontrei aqui no StackOverflow, e o modifiquei um pouco para se adequar ao meu formato final.

```
import pandas as pd

excel_names = ["1.xlsx", "2.xlsx", "3.xlsx", "4.xlsx", "5.xlsx"]

excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]

frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

combined = pd.concat(frames, join='outer', axis=1, sort=False)

combined.to_excel("final.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

O problema é que eu gostaria de relacionar algumas colunas e não sei como fazer, no caso, todas as tabelas tem ao menos uma coluna em comum que é o ID, eu gostaria que na tabela "final.xlsx", a coluna de ID fosse a mesma para todas as ocorrências de ID, e se possível, eliminar as repetições da coluna ID.

Também aceito soluções fora do código, como scripts para o Excel, para que eu possa ao menos organizar as linhas e colunas, relacionando-as com a coluna ID.